Why do proxy async API's sometimes return a 202 instead of a 200?
I was calling an internal service API through an external proxy API, but the responses I was getting were all 202's.  These were async API's, but they all return 200's when you call them directly on the internal service in Postman.  I couldn't find a lot of help by Googling the issue.  I suspect the issue is simply related to the extra processing steps that a proxy async API goes through.
My original controller function looked like this:
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetList")]
    [AuthorizationRequired]
    public ListModel GetList()
    {
        try
        {
            ListModel result = new Model();
        
            var R = _listAccess.GetList().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            result = R;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
            LogError(ex, msg);
            throw;
        }
    }

Looking at some other controllers as examples I experimented with some of the available classes. Ultimately, this controller solved the issue and this API started returning 200's in Postman:
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetList")]
    [AuthorizationRequired]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetList()
    {
        try
        {
            ListModel result = new ListModel();
            var R = await _listAccess.GetList();
            result = R;
            return new OkObjectResult(result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
            LogError(ex, msg);
            throw;
        }
    }

I would love for some more experienced developers to take a look at this and post any other suggestions in the comments.
